# Detect if user has reported current item

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

In my image viewer application, the users can report posts, and to do this, I use this code:

```
            let currentUpload = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "currentUploads", objectId: post.objID) // post.objID shows the current objectId for the selected row from parse.com class.

            currentUpload.incrementKey("timesReported")

            currentUpload.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (success) {
                    // The object has been incremented
                } else {
                    // There was a problem, check error.description
                }
            }
```

[image]

You can see how the images are stored, and on the right side, it tells how many times it has been reported. But the problem is, that the same user can report the same item multiple times.

Any suggestions on what i can do?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should have separate table(e.g. UserReported) that will keep record of which user has reported which post. And if record does not exists in that table then increment timesReported count in original reported(currentUploads).

Following is how you can use if user has already reported it UserReported table or not.
1. Use before save hook on parse cloud to check if user has already reported it or not. And ignore request accordingly. 
OR
2. You can query item before saving 
e.g. 
[How to prevent duplicate entry on parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838882/how-to-prevent-duplicate-entry-on-parse)

Comment: So i should create a string column for that in parse, and all the usernames that has reported the selected post, will be in the same column box, separated using a comma `,`?

Comment: Sorry I got your question little wrong. I'll edit my answer. 
May be in that case you should have separate table that will keep record of which user has reported which post. And if record does not exists in that table then increment count in reported posts.

Comment: OK, so if i understand you correct: Before executing the save query, i check if the user exist in the "UserReported" table somehow, and if it does not exist, it will execute the save query, or else, it will ignore? I have no idea how the code for this should be, with my code i already have..

Comment: I have this so far: http://pastebin.com/LBgbqUfs - It saves the username to a array, and it changes the timesReported count. BUT how do i check if the name already is inside the reportedBy?